# Building Dynamic Library for a complex project using makefiles on Linux

Tags: linux, makefile, shared-libraries

I'm trying to build a shared library on Linux having different modules, and since source files are spreded in different sub directories, I am having trouble figuring out how to create scripts and makefiles to compile the whole project as a single Dynamic shared Library with modules depending on other modules.

Could anyone please give me any examples or tutorials to help me ?

Comment: Do you know how to do it by hand, without scripts or makefiles?

Answer (score 0):

I always found this article useful:

[Static, Shared Dynamic and Loadable Linux Libraries](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html)

From there you'll want to do a [tutorial](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) on Make.

Comment: thanks, actually the library Im trying to build is a little bit more complicated, but it helped.